# The provider hashicorp/azurerm does not support resource type │ "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address"

Tags: terraform, azure-load-balancer

I am trying to create a Load Balancer in azure using `terraform` and I am getting this error:

> Error: Invalid resource type
> │
> │   on 12-lb.tf line 43, in resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "example":
> │   43: resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "example" {
> │
> │ The provider hashicorp/azurerm does not support resource type
> │ "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address".

And here's my `12-lb.tf`

```
resource "azurerm_lb" "example" {
  name                = "classiclb"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  sku                 = "Standard"

  frontend_ip_configuration {
    name                          = "classiclb"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.vm.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool" "example" {
  loadbalancer_id = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name            = "classiclb"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_probe" "example" {
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id     = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                = "classiclb"
  port                = 80
  interval_in_seconds = 10
  number_of_probes    = 3
  protocol            = "Http"
  request_path        = "/"
}

resource "azurerm_lb_rule" "example" {
  resource_group_name            = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  loadbalancer_id                = azurerm_lb.example.id
  name                           = "classiclb"
  protocol                       = "Tcp"
  frontend_port                  = 80
  backend_port                   = 80
  frontend_ip_configuration_name = "classiclb"
  backend_address_pool_id        = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  probe_id                       = azurerm_lb_probe.example.id
}

# the below is to be only used by when the sku of LB is set to Standard ony 
resource "azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address" "example" {
  name                    = "classiclb"
  backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
  virtual_network_id      = azurerm_virtual_network.example.id
  ip_address              = azurerm_linux_virtual_machine.example.private_ip_address
}

# the below is to be only used by when the sku of LB is set to Basic 
# resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "example" {
#   network_interface_id    = azurerm_network_interface.example.id
#   ip_configuration_name   = "internall"
#   backend_address_pool_id = azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool.example.id
# }
```

Why the resource `azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address` is not supported?

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear what you should do?

Answer (score 1):

> Why the resource azurerm_lb_backend_address_pool_address is not supported?

You have **old version** your your azurem provider. You have to **upgrade** it.